# Differing quantiles: Boxplot vs. Violinplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot, quantile, violin-plot

```
require(ggplot2)
require(cowplot)
d = iris

ggplot2::ggplot(d, aes(factor(0), Sepal.Length)) + 
    geom_violin(fill="black", alpha=0.2, draw_quantiles = c(0.25, 0.5, 0.75)
                , colour = "red", size = 1.5) +
    stat_boxplot(geom ='errorbar', width = 0.1)+
    geom_boxplot(width = 0.2)+
    facet_grid(. ~ Species, scales = "free_x") +
    xlab("") + 
    ylab (expression(paste("Value"))) +
    coord_cartesian(ylim = c(3.5,9.5)) + 
    scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(4, 9, 1)) + 
    theme(axis.text.x=element_blank(),
          axis.text.y = element_text(size = rel(1.5)),
          axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
          strip.background=element_rect(fill="black"),
          strip.text=element_text(color="white", face="bold"),
          legend.position = "none") +
    background_grid(major = "xy", minor = "none")
```

[image: boxplot vs. violinplot]

To my knowledge box ends in boxplots represent the 25% and 75% quantile, respectively, and the median = 50%. So they should be equal to the 0.25/0.5/0.75 quantiles which are drawn by `geom_violin` in the `draw_quantiles = c(0.25, 0.5, 0.75)` argument.

Median and 50% quantile fit. However, both 0.25 and 0.75 quantile do not fit the box ends of the boxplot (see figure, especially 'virginica' facet).

References:

1. http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_violin.html
2. http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_boxplot.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is too long for a comment, so I post it as an answer. I see two potential sources for the divergence. First, my understanding is that the `boxplot` refers to `boxplot.stats`, which uses `hinges` that are very similar but not necessarily identical to the quantiles.  `?boxplot.stats` says:

> The two ‘hinges’ are versions of the first and third quartile, i.e.,
>   close to quantile(x, c(1,3)/4). The hinges equal the quartiles for odd
>   n (where n <- length(x)) and differ for even n. Whereas the quartiles
>   only equal observations for n %% 4 == 1 (n = 1 mod 4), the hinges do
>   so additionally for n %% 4 == 2 (n = 2 mod 4), and are in the middle
>   of two observations otherwise.

The `hinge vs quantile` distinction could thus be one source for the difference.

Second, `geom_violin` refers to a density estimate. The source code [here](https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/6586743/) points to a function `StatYdensity`, which leads me to [here](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/blob/master/R/stat-ydensity.r). I could not find the function `compute_density`, but I think (also due to some pointers in help files) it is essentially `density`, which by default uses a Gaussian kernel estimate to estimate the density. This may (or may not) explain the differences, but

```
by(d$Sepal.Length, d$Species, function(x) boxplot.stats(x, coef=5)$stats )
by(d$Sepal.Length, d$Species, function(v) quantile(density(v)$x))
```

do show indeed differing values. So, I would guess that the difference is due to whether we look at quantiles based on the empirical distribution function of the observations, or based on kernel density estimates, though I admit that I have not conclusively shown this.

Comment: Your answer makes sense, thanks! The problems I see in all of these modifications of quantile values (either 'hinges' or density estimates) is that all refer to 'quantiles' in their last sense. `geom_boxplot` doc refers to "upper hinge, 75% quantile" while `geom_violin` doc calls it directly "draw_quantiles". This lets the user assume to deal with the same stats whereas both actually differ.

Answer (score 1):

The second factor [that @coffeinjunky raised](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36036821/570918) seems to be the main cause. Here is some more evidence to bolster that.

By switching to [`geom_ydensity`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_violin.html), one can empirically confirm that the difference is due to the `geom_violin` using the kernel density estimate to compute the quantiles, rather than the actual observations. For example, if we force a wide bandwidth (`bw=1`), then the estimated densities will be over-smoothed and deviate further from the observation-based quantiles used in the boxplots:

```
require(ggplot2)
require(cowplot)

theme_set(cowplot::theme_cowplot())

d = iris

ggplot2::ggplot(d, aes(factor(0), Sepal.Length)) + 
  stat_ydensity(bw=1, fill="black", alpha=0.2, draw_quantiles = c(0.25, 0.5, 0.75)
              , colour = "red", size = 1.5) +
  stat_boxplot(geom ='errorbar', width = 0.1)+
  geom_boxplot(width = 0.2)+
  facet_grid(. ~ Species, scales = "free_x") +
  xlab("") + 
  ylab (expression(paste("Value"))) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(3.5,9.5)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(4, 9, 1)) + 
  theme(axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = rel(1.5)),
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
        strip.background=element_rect(fill="black"),
        strip.text=element_text(color="white", face="bold"),
        legend.position = "none") +
  background_grid(major = "xy", minor = "none")
```

[image]

So, yes, be careful with this one - the parameters of the density estimation can impact the results!